# Failing to read input from .net-core console application in vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, ubuntu-17.10

I've been trying to get [dotnet new console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/dotnet) example project (for vscode) to work in Ubuntu 17.10.

I can get the default program to run:

```
using System;

namespace dotnet_console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

But when i change it to read input as well, it gets really wonky...

```
using System;

namespace dotnet_console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Name: "); // 1
            var name = Console.ReadLine(); // 2
            Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", name); // 3
        }
    }
}
```

The program builds, but it won't print `Name:`. However if i put breakpoints on line 1, 2 & 3, i can see that the program runs through ALL of them, but nothing prints. That is until i stop the debugging. Then it prints

> Name:
>
> The program '[16322] dotnet-console.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

What is happening here? I'm guessing its a vscode thing, because it works as expected when ran from the terminal using `dotnet run`.

Comment: @TobiasTheel The OP mentioned Ubuntu 17.10, so I am not sure why you think that testing on Windows is relevant

Comment: @TobiasTheel its not a doup, in this case WriteLine, works out of the box, but Write & ReadLine doesn't. However the same solution worked in both cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Documentation](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window) states the following:

> By default, processes are launched with their console output
>   (stdout/stderr) going to the VS Code Debugger Console. This is useful
>   for executables that take their input from the network, files, etc.
>   **But this does NOT work for applications that want to read from the
>   console (ex: Console.ReadLine).** For these applications, use a setting
>   such as the following

I found a solution for the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47778364/4992212).

And the following Quote from the linked Documentation also states that changing the console property from the launch.json to either "**externalTerminal**" or "**[integratedTerminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)** "is going to help.

> When this is set to *externalTerminal* the target process will run in a
>   separate terminal.
>
> When this is set to *integratedTerminal* the target process will run
>   inside VS Code's integrated terminal. Click the 'Terminal' tab in the
>   tab group beneath the editor to interact with your application.

[image: Location of launch.json]

Answer (score 2):

Correct - 'internalConsole' is not meant for programs that want to take console input. Here is the official documentation: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window