# Why i cant get any output from console.writeline

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a simple Hello World code in VSC(mac os)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Then i got

```
[Running] scriptcs -script "/Users/Username/Desktop/csharpstudy/test.cs"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.808 seconds
```

Any help please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Console.WriteLine work in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237146/why-doesnt-console-writeline-work-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Have you turned on the external console as described here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237146/why-doesnt-console-writeline-work-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ReadLine` too:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that the code exits so quickly that the dev simply never sees the output? Is that why you're adding a readline()?  Explanation would help.

Comment: i've already done but it didnt change